# Arquillian ShrinkWrap exclude import.sql

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm using Arquillian to test my ejb's. I have a separate project made for testing. I want to exclude `import.sql` file from deployment.

I already tried this:

```
.addAsResource("test-import.sql", "import.sql")
test-import.sql -empty file
```

But scripts are still executed.
Ideas?

Comment: Which persistent framework are you using? In case of Hibernate, it will try to invoke the sql scripts if the schema is created ie if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create or create-drop. You could  remove the script from the default sources and add it manually in your test code (addAsResource).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to exclude that file from the ShrinkWrap archive. There is a solution to delete files from that archive. So suppose that is added in a resource folder (like what is src/main/resources in Eclipse by default), you call:

`.delete("/WEB-INF/classes/import.sql")`